# Relative paths with MSBuild project vs solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a number of projects which are joined into a solution. Every project has it's own directory structure, and csproj files are located on diferrent level of folder structure.
Every csproj has OutputPath property specified. OutputPath - is a relative path and it varies from project to project in such a way so all projects have the same output dir.
It is work OK if I build a separate project. But everything changes if I try to build solution file. In this case every project output folder differs (depends on a number of '..\' in that project's OutputPath).

I do know, that before some moment all was working fine. Nobody changed build.cmd neither any sln or csproj files. But now I have situation described above.

So my question is - what affects how relative path is evaluated? I mean how can I force relative OutputPath to be evaluated starting from folder where csproj file of that particular project is located. Not from folder where .sln file is.

```
Let's assume I have following directory structure:

dir1
  a.sln
  dir2
    a.csproj
  dir21
    dir3
      b.csproj
```

a.csproj has output path set to '../../_bin' which is just above dir1 if counted from a.csproj folder
b.csproj has output path set to '../../../_bin' which is same - just about dir1 if counted from b.csproj

a.sln contains both - a.csproj and b.csproj.

When I run msbuild I get a project build to 'dir1/../../_bin' and b project to 'dir1/../../../_bin' - both relative paths of projects files are counted from solution file location, not project files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I was able to find out what was causing this. That was custom .targets file, which was inferring SolutionDir property at the start of any msbuild.
I did find out that by using MSBuild Explorer. The tool proved to be very useful in my case - I was not aware of third party .target files on my system.

Comment: +1000 I had the same root cause (overwriting $(OutputPath)) but very different problem (*.designer.cs files stopped regenerating) - diagnosed with MSBuild Explorer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

From [Msbuild Import Element description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx)

> Relative paths in imported projects are interpreted relative to the
>   directory of the importing project. Therefore, if a project file is
>   imported into several project files in different locations, the
>   relative paths in the imported project file will be interpreted
>   differently for each imported project.
>
> All MSBuild reserved properties that relate to the project file, for example, MSBuildProjectDirectory
>   and MSBuildProjectFile, that are referenced in an imported project are
>   assigned values based on the importing project file.

If you add more details or few samples to your question - it will be easier to understand exact problem.

Edit:
Okay, lets try to pinpoint that mystery. First of all - OutputPath could be affected by Environment variables.

2nd - during build sln file transformed into msbuild project file format and stored in temp file. You can get that temporary file if you execute in cmd "set msbuildemitsolution=1" and then trigger build via command line. There you can check that file and see how your individual projects called. But I suppose you will see multiple .csproj /> entries. And global msbuild properties inherited by that calls.

So I suspect if everything was fine before some point and no changes were made - you are missing OutputPath environment variable or some other variable that contributed to construction of OutputPath.

BTW - I think if you want to fix your issue with forcing relative dir  - you also can use $(MSBuildProjectDirectory). This is one of msbuild reserved properties (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164309.aspx)), but this will require yo adjust your OutputPath in each csproj file. What i, personally, prefer to avoid, because it could affect some other targets and introduce subtle issues.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by imported projects, but in my case all relative paths are interpreted relative to the directory of solution files. And I am not sure how to change that...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I fixed problem and mentioned that in my own answer above. But thanks for participation anyway!